# SwiftUI: Put Segment Control (Picker) in navigation bar below Searchbar?

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationview

I am trying to code up a list invite a Navigation view that is also using `searchable`:

```
.searchable(text: $query, placement: .toolbar, prompt: "Search")
```

The view I put the Picker in looks like this:

```
struct FolderView: View {
    let title: String
    let mails: [Mail]
    @Binding var selectedMail: Mail?
    @State private var selectedColorIndex = 0
    

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Picker("Favorite Color", selection: $selectedColorIndex, content: {
                           Text("Red").tag(0)
                           Text("Green").tag(1)
                           Text("Blue").tag(2)
                       })
                       .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            
            
            ForEach(mails) { mail in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: MailView(mail: mail),
                    tag: mail,
                    selection: $selectedMail
                ) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(mail.subject)
                        Text(mail.date, style: .date)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.navigationTitle(title)
    }
}
```

The screen looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to put the segment control inside the navigation bar below the search bar so it looks grouped together and not part of the list...

That would allow me to search and filter. depending on the picked segment.

How can I put the picker view inside the navigation bar?

As the provided answers state, putting the Picker in the `.toolbar` modifier like so:

```
 .toolbar {
                Picker("Favorite Color", selection: $selectedColorIndex, content: {
                               Text("Red").tag(0)
                               Text("Green").tag(1)
                               Text("Blue").tag(2)
                           })
                           .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            }
```

Makes it look like this:

[image]

The other thing I mentioned in my question is that I am trying to put the Picker below the search bar. Is there a way to do to so?
Do I have to write my custom search view implementation where I'd have a search bar in it and any other view I want, to be able to put the picker below the search bar?

EDIT:

Adding code that shows how I am adding the search bar as requested:

```
var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            Sidebar(
                store: store,
                selectedFolder: $selectedLabel,
                selectedMail: $selectedMail
            )
            
            Text("Select label...")
            Text("Select mail...")
        }
        .searchable(text: $query, placement: .toolbar, prompt: "Search")
    }
```

Comment: show us the code where and how you add your search view. Then we can have a crack at adding the toolbar below it.

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to get your code to work as is, but I created a sample project with some code on my end.

If I understand the question correctly, you want to get the "red, green, blue" picker into the navigation bar.

To do this you need to use the `.toolbar` modifier on the navigation view. Doing this will allow you to add additional items to the toolbar.

Additionally, you can modify the `ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading)` to change the position of the picker. If not needed, you can remove this line altogether.

```
   struct ContentView: View {
    let title: String
    @State private var selectedColorIndex = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("placeholder")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Picker("Favorite Color", selection: $selectedColorIndex, content: {
                            Text("Red").tag(0)
                            Text("Green").tag(1)
                            Text("Blue").tag(2)
                        })
                            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Inbox")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to put your Picker  inside the navigation bar, you can try this, note
you will have to adjust the position as you see fit.

```
struct FolderView: View {
   let title: String
   let mails: [Mail]
   @Binding var selectedMail: Mail?
   @State private var selectedColorIndex = 0

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(mails, id: \.id) { mail in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: MailView(mail: mail),
                    tag: mail,
                    selection: $selectedMail
                ) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(mail.subject)
                        Text(mail.date, style: .date)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(title)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
                    Picker("Favorite Color", selection: $selectedColorIndex, content: {
                        Text("Red").tag(0)
                        Text("Green").tag(1)
                        Text("Blue").tag(2)
                    }).pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you beat me to it!

Comment: first time for me to beat anyone. Cheers.